# Remove WearableRecyclerView extra top space

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0

My Watchface Config activity has just a WearableRecyclerView with settings. When I run the activity in Wear Emulator, there seem to be a lot of extra space at the top. Unable to figure out how to remove it.

**Activity Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView android:id="@+id/setting_recycler_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `void setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled (boolean isEnabled)` to control this behavior.

From the `WearableRecyclerView` [documentation](http://setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled):

> Use this method to configure the WearableRecyclerView to always align the first and last items with the vertical center of the screen. This effectively moves the start and end of the list to the middle of the screen if the user has scrolled so far. It takes the height of the children into account so that they are correctly centered.